# Syntax for using variables inside of row or range function?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to clear some cells at the end of the data I need. What I have is this:

```
'to find the last row of my data
usedRows = Sheets("Formatted").Range("T" & Sheets("Formatted").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'to clear the 12 rows after my data
Worksheets("Formatted").Rows(usedRows+1:usedRows+12).Clear
```

However, the second line of code doesn't work. I'm not sure what the proper syntax is for variables inside the row function.

Alternatively, I was also looking into using a range function to do the same thing. The only shortcoming I realized was that when using a range function, you have to specify a column as well right? If so, then I would have to specify the ending column. I had this code:

```
Worksheets("Formatted").Range(.Cells("A", usedRows+1), .Cells("IV", usedRows+12)).Clear
```

But this syntax was incorrect as well. Would love to know the proper syntax for both to have more flexibility in the future.

Comment: `Worksheets("Formatted").Rows(usedRows+1 & ":" & usedRows+12).Clear`

Comment: You've got the order of `Cells` arguments backwards in the second snippet, but you don't need `Cells` either: `.Range("A" & usedRows + 1 & ":IV" & usedRows + 12)`